# Why does Chrome struggle to render emojis when using Typed.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, emoji, typed.js

I'm using [Typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) to type out different words into a header. When using emojis, it works great in every browser I've tested other than Chrome on MacOS (v71.0.3578), where it struggles to render the emoji character and flickers a question mark for a fraction of a second before displaying the correct emoji. Screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I've seen in a few React-related questions that removing `font-weight:bold` fixes some emoji rendering issues, but not in this case.

My options are set up like this, with emoji characters inputted directly into the code:

```
var options = {
    strings: ["First word.", ".", "Second word."],
    typeSpeed: 80,
    startDelay: 1000,
    backDelay: 1000,
    backSpeed: 40,
    onComplete: function() { 
        setTimeout( function() {
            jQuery('.typed-cursor').hide();
        }, 1000); 
    }
}
```

Works great in Safari, iOS and even IE11, but Chrome is struggling. What gives?

Comment: have you solved this? got the same problem here :/

Comment: I'm afraid not. Do let me know if you work out a fix!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few years late, but I ran into the same problem and ended up solving it by using the hex codes in the string, instead of the actual emojis https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp

Comment: It helps but there is only a limited number of emojis, is there any page with codes for all available emojis e.g. like https://emojipedia.org/ ?